# Text substitution in MySQL SQL Pass-Thru

Tags: mysql, sql-like, slashdb

I am using SlashDB for a REST API (SQL Pass-thru) for MySQL.

This allows you to write a SQL query where your parameters (to be replaced by user text) are preceeded by `:`.  For example:

`select * from mydb where name = :name;`

would work fine, assuming that -- if name represents a value that might be changed to "Atlanta" -- that what you want is:

`select * from mydb where name = 'Atlanta';`

The problem is that I am trying to use `like` with wildcards at the beginning and end of the parameter. The query I **want** to run is:

`select * from mydb where name like '%Atlanta%';`

but when I input

`select * from mydb where name like '%:name%';`

the result is:

`select * from mydb where name like '%'Atlanta'%';`

which of course does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. It can be a little tricky but here's how you can accomplish this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mydb
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', :name, '%')
```

P.S. Please tag your SlashDB questions with tag: slashdb